# keyOrKeyArray must be an instance of Firebase\\JWT\\Key key or an array of Firebase\\JWT\\Key keys", in php ci4

Tags: php

{
"title": "UnexpectedValueException",
"type": "UnexpectedValueException",
"code": 500,
"message": "$keyOrKeyArray must be an instance of Firebase\JWT\Key key or an array of Firebase\JWT\Key keys",
"file": "E:\var\www\html\project\spans\admin\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php",
"line": 416,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below example code -

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

class User extends BaseController
{
    public function exampleMethod()
    {
        $issuedAt = time();
        $expirationTime = $issuedAt + 60;  // jwt valid for 60 seconds from the issued time
        $payload = array( // Any random data
            'userid' => 'Test_UID',
            'name' => 'Sankhnad Mishra',
            'iat' => $issuedAt,
            'exp' => $expirationTime
        );
        $key = 'A_JWT_SECRET'; // Any string
        $alg = 'HS256'; // This is alg

        $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, $alg); // Encode payload as a JWT Token
        $decodedToken = JWT::decode($token, new Key($key, 'HS256')); // Decode token to a payload

        $response = [
            'token' => $token,
            'decodedToken' => $decodedToken
        ];

        print_r($response);
    }
}
```

If you run above then you will get the below response -

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJUZXN0X1VJRCIsIm5hbWUiOiJTYW5raG5hZCBNaXNocmEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDU4MTU0OTUsImV4cCI6MTY0NTgxNTU1NX0.0CwT9quW8-teyob3ObRU5KQBfQYWamCSTVCrAk9UX-o",
    "decodedToken": {
        "userid": "Test_UID",
        "name": "Sankhnad Mishra",
        "iat": 1645815495,
        "exp": 1645815555
    }
}
```

So, just pick those pieces of code from above based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you make use of namespace

```
Use Firebase\JWT\Key;

// For encode:

$jwt = JWT: encoding ($payload, $key, 'HS256');

// For decoding: 

$decodedToken = JWT:: decode ($jwt, new key ($key,'HS256'));
```